# Why chartJs throws length of undefined although everything seems correct

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, chart.js, ng2-charts

I have very basic chart object contains xAxis array for chartData and yAxis for chartLabels like below

```
  public charts=[
    {
      xAxis : [
     1,2,3,4,5,6
      ],
       yAxis : [
      10,11,12,13,14,15
      ]
    },
    {
       xAxis : [
     2,2,4,7,8,9
      ],
       yAxis : [
      11,15,14,33,24,16
      ]
    } 
  ]
```

And here its the way how I iterate them and create canvas on HTML side

```
<div id="chart-container" *ngIf="charts">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let item of charts">
    <canvas  id="canvas" baseChart [chartType]="chartType" [datasets]="item.xAxis" [labels]="item.yAxis"  [options]="chartOptions"></canvas>
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

But it throws ERROR like below

```
Error: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

I dont know really why it happens.I hope someone can solve this and help me

Stackblitz example : https://stackblitz.com/edit/line-chart-nlucvd?file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: Try to print out item inside the loop and see if it has a value or it's undefined.

Comment: Console.log(charts) works fine I'm able to print everything that I defined on .ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stackblitz demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/line-chart-xmy3vt?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

You need an appropriate data format to pass to you chart canvas element based on the official example (array + object with data keyword)

```
 public lineChartData: ChartDataSets[] = [
    { data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]},
  ];
```

Changed html which gives the output

```
<div id="chart-container" *ngIf="charts">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let item of charts;let i=index">
        <canvas id="canvas" baseChart [chartType]="chartType" [datasets]="[dataSet[i]]" [labels]="item.yAxis">
        </canvas>
    </ng-container>
</div>
```